# Avoid UI Blocking while running an operation that requires to be run on the main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I use an API that has a method, let's say `run()` that must be executed on the main thread, or else it'll throw an exception. Now, I've tried coroutines, and it doesn't work in a standard `launch{...}` block, which is understandable. Now, since it is a little long running task, I wish to show a UI to the user, indicating the same, i.e., a process is taking place. Now, I do not require assistance on the animation logic, but I cannot understand how is the animation supposed to keep up alongside all the heavy IO stuff that may be going on on the main thread.

Also, I've been experiencing some very odd behaviour in this Composable. Kingly have a look,

```
    @Composable
    fun CustomC() {
        var trigger by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }

        val color by animateColorAsState(targetValue = if (trigger) Color.Gray else Color.Cyan)

        Surface(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.background(color),
                text = "Running"
            )
        }

// I tried this but this seems to produce a crash, indicating that the run method is not running on the main thread, but how? Removing this LaunchedEffect removes the error. 

//        LaunchedEffect(Unit){
//            delay(2000)
//            trigger = true
//        }

        run() // Must be executed on the Main Thread
    }
```

This app crashes if I put that `LaunchedEffect` block over there, but it is not even  interacting with `run()` in any way, per my knowledge. And another strange behaviour is as follows:

```
    @Composable
    fun CustomC() {
        var trigger by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }

        val color by animateColorAsState(targetValue = if (trigger) Color.Gray else Color.Cyan)
        Surface(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.background(color),
                text = "Running"
            )
        }
        trigger = true
        run() // Must be executed on the Main Thread
    }
```

Now, you would expect the Composable to be turning Cyan before the run method is called, right? IT DOESN'T!! IT  JUST DOESN'TTTT

It just starts executing `run()` and then finally AFTER the method is done executing, the Composable turns cyan. This clearly implies that the recompositions are blocked while the method is running, so all I need is a way to get around that.

EDIT: An important piece of information that I missed earlier, when I call the `run()` method inside of a `LaunchedEffect`, the method seems to work fine, i.e., the app doesn't crash, but the UI is still blocked.

Also, if I call the method inside a `launch` block WITHIN a `LaunchedEffect`, the same thing happens as above, where the method runs fine but the UI is clogged. What is the role of `launch` here then?

FINAL EDIT: A very rare thing I saw in this scenario was when the crash appeared, it did not throw any sort of an exception. It just raised an error like so:

```
 Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x2f6000412f6018 in tid 29693
```

I got this error from my search history, and it pointed me to some things related to programming in the NDK, which I do not. Also, now no matter what I do, the error won't come up. Seems like a glitch in Android or Studio.

Comment: You shouldn't be running IO tasks on the main (UI) thread. That will block it.  You should be using a viewmodel that executes your IO task in a coroutine that runs on the IO thread.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, so you have to run some operation that you don't control, it has to be run on the main thread and is blocking, then... well, you are basically screwed. I don't think you can do anything about it. You just have to redesign/rewrite this `run()` function, because the problem is inside it. And yes, it is expected that it turns cyan after the long running operation, because while it is running, UI is blocked and can't even change the color.

Comment: Have you tried executing it from within `LaunchedEffect`? It is executed in a coroutine running in the main thread.

Comment: @Johann, I figured it out almost exactly as you might have posted this comment, that the operation can be run in an IO thread nested in a coroutine, but your idea about transferring all of this into the viewmodel and running it from there in the first place really helps. I just implemented that and it works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @broot I appreciate the optimism, fellow stackoverflower (flowiee? Debate open). Now, it is true that this needed to be run on the main thread, and that it would potentially be blocking, but if you refer to the question again, just above my first code block, I explained that the function needs to perform IO operations and hence, required to be run on the main thread, since separate threads don't seem to have access to writes and similar operations. Now, that problem was simply overcome by wrapping it in a coroutine that runs on the IO threads, allowing IO access without blocking the main thred

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Thank you for the  reply, sir. I forgot to mention this scenario. I am fairly experienced with jetpack compose so this was one of the first solutions that I tried. Kindly check the edit in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Johann sir I will be providing an answer here with my specific use-case, but since you posted the explanation for the general use-case, please feel free to post an answer on this thread with the info and I'll be happy to accept it as the accepted answer. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Stark Sorry, it is really hard to follow you. "I explained that the function needs to perform IO operations and hence, required to be run on the main thread" - this sentence doesn't make any sense to me. If it performs IO operations then this is exactly why it should **not** be executed on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Since the cause of the crash seems to be the method was not given access to I/O by the system, the problem was resolved using a coroutine with I/O access.

Now, in my `ViewModel`, I wrapped the run method in a coroutine like this

```
suspend fun runWithIO(){ // custom method
 withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
  run() // The original method, provided by the API
 }
}
```

This satisfies all the constraints, whatsoever - Runs on a thread with I/O access, does not block the Main Thread, uses best practices like coroutines without any side-effects.

So, the explanation was posted by Johann in the first comment on the original post which has just been adapted to my specific use-case here.

So, if an API that you might be using states that the methods are supposed to be run only on the main thread, you should probably play around for a while with different coroutine contexts, since the API may only require the main thread to perform I/O operations, which can also be performed in a simple coroutine like this. If the method does indeed require the main thread, there's also `Dispatchers.Main` to assist you with that, you can run only the required part of a function on the Main Thread, but please note, this call WILL BE blocking.